# Database schema for a social network website? MySql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb, express

Actually i am from MongoDB background and have a basic knowledge about MySql databases , I want to create a social networking website and i cant figure out that what should be my schema if i was to use MySql(I am gonna use mysql)
My data is =
username
passowrd
email
collegename
posts (posts will contain the number of posts user has posted so u can consider it as array[Post] , it will also have replies , likes , if the post contains any photo i am gonna store url of that photo too)
representing post in a object format for better understanding

```
Post {
   title:String,
   body:String,
   imageURL:String,
   Likes:Number,
   Replies:[Post]
}
```

so that's pretty much it
Extra info = I am gonna use mysql via myphpadmin that xampp offers , using nodejs and expressjs technology for website
And My Intention behind using MySql is because its cheap comparing to MongoDB
Please help me i am really stuck on this and have tried many solutions but got no luck , thank you

Comment: for SQL, you need to access the SQL DB and create the table beforehand.

Something like this

CREATE TABLE Post (
    title varchar(255),
    body varchar(255),
   ....
);

Comment: @Darkripper ,and than how can i add this post to the post column in userData , considering there are 2 tables one named userData which contains username and password etc and the 2nd table named posts , ok than how can i relate that 2nd table to first , is that what you are saying , please elaborate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Social web application database design: how can I improve this schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844477/social-web-application-database-design-how-can-i-improve-this-schema)